# dataframe into to list of dictonaries without the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
 NY       FL      IL      GA      CA
80.0    30.0    60.0    NaN     NaN
90.0    NaN     NaN     10.0    20.0
```

When i do as below

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1)
```

i get

```
0    {'NY': 80.0, 'FL': 30.0, 'IL': 60.0}
1    {'NY': 90.0, 'GA': 10.0, 'CA': 20.0}
dtype: object
```

but what i want is

```
list =  [{'NY':80,'FL':30, 'IL':60}, {'NY':90, 'GA':10, 'CA':20 }]
```

How do i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the result `tolist()`:

```
In [1235]: df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1).tolist()
Out[1235]: [{'NY': 80.0, 'FL': 30.0, 'IL': 60.0}, {'NY': 90.0, 'GA': 10.0, 'CA': 20.0}]
```

In case if all values are numeric and the result requires integers - add imtermediate `.astype(int)` call:

```
In [1241]: df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().astype(int).to_dict(), axis=1).tolist()
Out[1241]: [{'NY': 80, 'FL': 30, 'IL': 60}, {'NY': 90, 'GA': 10, 'CA': 20}]
```

Comment: I was pondering this... but wasn't sure if things now being `int`s (as per example output in the Q) instead of `float`s was a requirement of the output...

Comment: @JonClements, I've added an additional update for that case.

Comment: Not sure if it's something to build on, but was thinking along the lines of `df.stack().astype(int)`, but at that point, couldn't think of a convenient way to get it to a list of dicts in a way that's efficient...

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[{k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if not np.isnan(v)} for d in df.to_dict(orient="rows")]`

Comment: for me droping the NaN items in important. I cannot use `orient='rows'` inside of `df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1)`

Comment: Then this is your code: `[{k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if not np.isnan(v)} for d in df.to_dict(orient="rows")] `